# list view from xml

Tags: android, xml, listview

Please see [this image](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=ff66fda), I want to show my SMSes in this form , please help me

This is xml file :

```
<smses count="2">

<sms 
    protocol="0" 
    address="123" 
    date="1356069180000" 
    type="1" 
    subject="null" 
    body="nDGd0Or7LQCajC+GSkQFDw==" 
    toa="null" 
    sc_toa="null" 
    service_center="null" 
    read="0" 
    status="0" 
    locked="0" 
    date_sent="0" 
    readable_date="Dec 21, 2012 5:53:00 AM" 
    contact_name="(Unknown)"/>

<sms 
    protocol="0" 
    address="123" 
    date="1356069181021" 
    type="1" 
    subject="null" 
    body="hw r u" 
    toa="null" 
    sc_toa="null" 
    service_center="null" 
    read="0" 
    status="-1" 
    locked="0" 
    date_sent="1356069180000" 
    readable_date="Dec 21, 2012 5:53:01 AM" 
    contact_name="(Unknown)"/>
</smses>
```

.

```
try{    
    File fXmlFile = new File(/mnt/sdcard/myxmlfile.xml);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("sms");
    pDialog.setMax(nl.getLength());
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Node nNode = nl.item(i);
        Element e = (Element) nNode;
        String number= getNodeAttributeByTagName(nNode, "address");
        map.put(KEY_ADDRESS,number);
        map.put("body",getNodeAttributeByTagName(nNode, "body"));
        map.put(KEY_CONTACT, getContactDisplayNameByNumber(number));
        menuItems.add(map);
        String y = String.valueOf(i);
        publishProgress(y);
    }
  }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

show in list

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(showlist.this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item_albums,
                new String[] { KEY_CONTACT, "body", KEY_ADDRESS }, new int[] {
                R.id.contact, R.id.body, R.id.address  });
        list1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: and click list view show image like this , plz give me hint hw it will done,[link](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=db4b1aa)

Comment: reading file from xml file and xml webservices has same kind of work.. except the HTTP support. to show those contents you need to use Listview in android. Need to design the child items for that list view . according to that you can show all the contents correctly.

Comment: So, where is the question? What is your problem?

Comment: @Sver in first line , how to show xml in that form, i want to group my all sms in group form as like in image , which i attach with question

Comment: @Rajesh , m using list view  already to all sms , but i want to show sms in group, in simple way i can easily show

Comment: @Rajesh, m reading xml by this function, which is defined in my code,
getNodeAttributeByTagName(nNode, "address");, it return  address from xml , and i bind it with "R.id.address" by using R.layout.list_item_albums layout design... plz help how i show my xml file in this form [sample](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=ff66fda)

Comment: You are using getview for that?  do you know how to bind simple list view with BaseAdapter ?

Comment: @Rajesh no sir, i dnt read about this

Comment: k ... so first learn how to bind the list view using adapters with getview.. and inflate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rohit: you have to create a custom view for each row.

see this  [ListView](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)  tutorial.